# What are the golden apples in Happy Jump?

Tags: happy-jump

What special powers do the golden apples give you in Happy Jump for the Kindle Fire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Golden apples gives a x2 rocket boost greater then a red apple. It also allows you to kill flys.